# How can I ignore Excel cell value if text is struck through?

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

I'm parsing an Excel spreadsheet using Microsoft's Excel Interop.  I was instructed to ignore any values that have been "stricken through" (see image).

[image]

The code I'm using to get the value is simple:

`string cellValue = Convert.ToString(cell.Value);`

Maybe I could check each character in the `cellValue` to see if its ASCII code is beyond an acceptable range?

EDIT: With the help of the answer below, I was able to solve this by doing the following:

```
if (cellValue.Font.Strikethrough)
{
  continue;
}
  else
{
  // process value
}
```

Comment: I would rather think you could find it in the formatting options, as a strike through option somewhere

Comment: I tried the same thing, but the IDE says there is no method font for string. Am I missing an assembly reference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should retrieve the Cell Format. I don't have excel here but I think it should be something like:

```
myworksheet.Cells[row, col].Font.Strikethrough;
```

See this question: [Reading text format from Excel using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11649399/reading-text-format-from-excel-using-microsoft-office-interop-excel)

If that doesn't work, look at answer of Danny, he tells you should check if a character is StrikeTrough.

Comment: Awesome!  Your answer led me to how to accomplish this.  As soon as the timer is up, I'll mark the answer!  Thank you very much!